# Qt MOC generated code documentation

Tags: c++, qt, moc

I am designing a user interface in Qt, and for longevity reasons I'd like to not require the Qt Meta-Object Compiler be used in future builds. I know the MOC parses certain macros in standard C++ code and generates C++ code based on these.

What I'd like to know is: where is the documentation of this generated code? I'd like to write the generated code directly into my relevant classes. While this might be cumbersome to do now, it will make the UI more stable in the long term by avoiding any issues if Qt disappears and the MOC ceases to exist.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**
I am designing a Qt based UI in Visual Studio (NOT Qt Creator), for a C++ application that is not based on the Qt framework. I want to be able to distribute code that can be built as pure C++ with Qt code linked from specific libraries that will be packaged in. I want to be able to build this code on systems that do not have Qt installed. Hence the desire to avoid MOC. I'm not trying to offend any Qt fans out there, Qt is great. However, I need something a little different on this project, so suggestions to "Just use MOC" are not at all helpful.

**Edit 2:** I'm man enough to admit when I'm wrong. After some more thought and research it's clearly not worth trying what I was planning on doing. I'll just have to save the MOC generated code and distribute it as well. Thanks everyone.

Comment: `moc` has existed for a long time, I don't know about any plan to phase it out.  Besides, I'm sure that the generated code is seen as an internal detail, and as such it can be changed without compatibility considerations.  In short, I strongly believe your code would be far more vulnerable if you sneak it below the `moc` abstraction.

Comment: I'd rather keep my build process less complex and use pure C++ without the QT preprocessing step. This must be possible, the QT generated code must be available somewhere..

Comment: This is kind of silly. You're worried about Qt vanishing, so you want to hard-code the moc code? So what happens when Qt vanishes? What do you use to replace your Qt run-times? What of all the headaches that will come when the next version of Qt expects the moc code to work in a way different than what your hard-coded files do? You know that changes in your code usually will ripple into the moc-generated code, right? How will you generate these files without moc when you make changes? If this is your mindset of future-proofing, moc is the least of your problems.

Comment: I package the qt libraries for distribution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Qt will be around longer than your application. Don't waste your time doing something so pointless than coding by hand a lot of complex boilerplate code when there is an automated tool, moc, for that. Why don't you put the moc'ed files to your version control, if you are afraid of not being able to generate those anymore? Please, for the sake of the future maintainers of your code, just use moc.

Comment: If you're truly worried about Qt disappearing, make sure you separate your UI-code from the rest of your system. And perhaps don't rely on the Qt framework for the rest of your non-UI system. But don't try to somehow circumvent MOC. That is just plain silly. P.s. afaik there is no public specification of MOC and its output.

Comment: The UI code is already separate from the main application. For various reasons I have no choice but to do my best to find a way around MOC. So I appreciate your comment @Bart because that's what I'm worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting moc output verbatim into your code makes your code less portable, not more, as the moc output format changes more often (currently version 67) than source-incompatible major versions of Qt (currently version 5).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be on the whole not worth it to try to circumvent the MOC, as everyone here has pointed out to me. My solution will be saving the MOC generated source files in source control and packaging them along with the main application code for distribution.